# CIFS share on Freenas not giving full control to AD users

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, cifs, truenas

I've managed to setup a FreeNAS server and connect it to AD. My problem comes when I try to edit permissions from windows. I already set the owner to be an AD user that I'm logged in with, but when I try to edit a dir ACL and apply the changes I made I get a "Parameter invalid" error.

I checked better and I've noticed that CIFS only gives rwx permissions (but not Full Control), so I can't change or give any permissions myself from Windows. Windows ACL is correctly selected, but still I don't get a user with "Full control" checked in Windows ACL, thus preventing me from making the server of any use. Can you help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: So after looking again for solutions, I found out it is a UFS problem which I solved by switching to ZFS. Sadly I couldn't figure out what was the issue with UFS, but atleast I've got my system running.

Comment: You should make that an answer for this question and then select it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking again for solutions, I found out it is a UFS problem which I solved by switching to ZFS. Sadly I couldn't figure out what was the issue with UFS, but atleast I've got my system running.